# How to shift last word of paragraph to next line without using any tag because content is coming dynamic

Tags: html

My content is coming dynamically, and content is in "p" tag i want last word of paragraph should be shifted to next line.Without adding "span" or any other tag. Is there any css ??

Comment: Why adding a tag is not an option? inserting a <br/> before last word would be the easiest way to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is use JavaScript. I wrote a pice of code with jQuery to accomplish your task.

https://codepen.io/Czeran/pen/yoXGVb

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var text = $('p').html();
  var splitedText = text.split(" ");
  splitedText.splice(splitedText.length-1, 0, '<br>');
  var joinedText = splitedText.join(" ");
  $('p').empty();
  $('p').html(joinedText);
});
```

Unfortunatelly I don't know any CSS or HTML way to do it.